# to extract a point between 3 intersect circle in matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry

code to extract a node (point) between 3 intersect circles with same radius in matlab

```
Dist_Source_Neighbour(i)=((SourceX - NodeX(i))^2 +  (SourceY-NodeY(i))^2)^(0.5);
    Angle_Source_Neighbour(i)=atan2(NodeY(i)-SourceY, NodeX(i)-SourceX )* 180/pi;
     Distance_between_Centers(i) = ((SourceX - NodeX(i))^2 +  (SourceY-NodeY(i))^2)^(0.5);
     Sum_of_neigbour_radius = 2*radius;
```

I just tried this one but is not working!

Comment: Could you post the input and the expected output, please.

Comment: function [NoOfThirdNode,NodeNoOfThirdNode]=FindThirdNodeForEachNode(SourceX,SourceY,NodeX,NodeY,Link)